# Unable to use custom master file in DisplayForm

Tags: 2010, custom-masterpage, display-form

So I am attempting to use a custom master file for the DisplayForm on a list. The only customization is that it is v4.master but with a different X-UA-Compatible browser chosen.

When I go to attach the custom master file, I go to the "Select Specific Master Page" option and choose the custom.master i created. I then get Match Content Regions page, which tells me PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass doesnt match PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead on the Master Page.

The problem is if I Modify it to match, the css in the page breaks and everything looks terrible.

What am I doing wrong in this process? Seems like it should be easy to pick a custom master file with such a small change from the original.

Comment: modifying X-UA-Compatible in 2010 causes all sorts of weird issues. I would advise against customizing that.

Comment: In this case, i need to... Fortunately I only need it for the DisplayForm of one list.